# SSMS SQL DATEDIFF Function - Calculating Time Between Dates

Tags: sql, datetime, logic, sql-server-2014, datediff

I'm using SMSS 2014.

I'm trying to calculate the time between Days, Hours, Minutes, and Seconds with the DateDiff function.

What I'm trying to solve for is for times when the Hour/Minute/Second difference is negative, and then adjusting the negative value for that (which I think I did correctly by adding 24 or 60 to it based on the time type) and also adding to the day (not sure how to do that.)

I appreciate any help.

My code is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(t.Days) as Days,
    AVG(t.Hours)as Hours,
    AVG(t.Minutes)as Minutes,
    AVG(t.Seconds) as Seconds
FROM
    (SELECT
         DATEDIFF(dd,DateAcknow,DateResolv) as Days,
         Hours = CASE
                    WHEN DateDiff(hh, TimeAcknow, TimeResolv) < 0 
                      THEN 24 + DateDiff(hh, TimeAcknow, TimeResolv)
                    ELSE DateDiff(hh, TimeAcknow, TimeResolv) 
                 END,
         Minutes = CASE
                      WHEN DateDIFF(mi, TimeAcknow,TimeResolv) % 60 < 0 
                        THEN 60 + DateDIFF(mi, TimeAcknow,TimeResolv) % 60
                        ELSE DateDIFF(mi, TimeAcknow,TimeResolv) % 60 
                   END,
         Seconds = CASE
                      WHEN DateDIFF(ss, TimeAcknow,TimeResolv) % 60 < 0 
                        THEN 60 + DateDIFF(ss, TimeAcknow, TimeResolv) % 60
                        ELSE DateDIFF(ss, TimeAcknow, TimeResolv) % 60 
                   END
     FROM 
         [HEAT8].[dbo].[Asgnmnt]
     WHERE 
         DateASsign >= '2016-03-01'
         AND GroupName = 'CS NonUrgent'
         AND DateResolv <> '') AS t
```

Comment: Tag the dbms used. `datediff()` is product specific!

Comment: Thanks, I will do that.